# Very slow page loading and delayed prompt in SSH, even though ping, download speeds are fine

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, wicd

Couple of facts:

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04
I use Cisco AnyConnect to connect to my company VPN (though websites are slow without it)
I'm always using my home 2.4 Ghz wi-fi network. Other devices which use this wi-fi hotspot (smartphones etc.) don't have this problem.

The problem is that after like 30 minutes of working on a freshly booted laptop networking slows down to a crawl so:

- pages load slowly
- when I press a letter while in SSH to an Azure VM the letter appears in the terminal after 1 second

Ookla speedtest show: 13ms ping, 100Mbps download, 10Mbps upload

What I've tried:

1. Uncommented `precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100` in /etc/gai.conf because I've heard there are some problems with ipv6, but I don't know what I'm doing. This didn't change anything at all.
2. Cisco AnyConnect edits /etc/resolv.conf with it's own DNS values. I changed the contents of /etc/resolv.conf to `nameserver 1.1` (cloudflare dns). This also did not help.

Perhaps it could be because I have both NetworkManager and wicd installed? I do sudo apt remove wicd but it says it's not installed, even though I can still launch wicd from the app menu.

Linux networking is black magic to me and I really have no idea what's happening here. What else can I do?

Comment: Find out where in the route the bottleneck is: `traceroute [remote-server]` (assuming there is one persistently slow link between you and the server).

Comment: I got a sample traceroute of a slow connection to portal.azure.com (https://gist.github.com/3nuc/b1b471cae423f2dedee369821be178e2). High latency in the beginning stages indicates this is either my router or the ISP, right?